# Build list of links using Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have passed a list of strings to my Jinja2 template.  I want to use Jinja2 to `join` the list but I want to also convert each list item to a `href`.  Is it possible or do I need to somehow pass the links to the template?

```
# I use this to join the list items.

{{ my_list|join(', ') }}

# I use this to make links individually

{% for i in my_list %}

    <a href="/edit/{{ i }}">i</a>

{% endfor %}
```

How can I convert the items to links before/as they are joined?

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't believe this is possible using Jinja2 alone.  The way I ended up fixing it was to build the comma separated list of anchor tags in Python before passing it to Jinja2.  Then I had to tell Jinja2 that the HTML was `safe`.

Return this from my Pyramid view:

```
result['list_string'] = ', '.join(['<a href="view/%s">i._name</a>' % i._id\
         for i in objects])
return result
```

Then in the template:

```
{{ list_string|safe }}
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`loop` special variable of `for` loops](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for):

```
{% for i in my_list %}
    <a href="/edit/{{ i }}">i</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You could also wrap this in a macro:

```
{% macro listlinks(mylist, urltemplate="/edit/%s", connective=", ") -%}
    {% for item in mylist -%}
        <a href="{{ urltemplate|format(item)|e }}">{{ item|e }}</a>
        {% if not loop.last %}{{ connective|e }}{% endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}


{{ listlinks(list_of_ids) }}
```

However, I recommend you not build pathnames into your templates as @Demian suggests in his answer. It is better to have pathnames built outside of templates via some abstracted mechanism, e.g., like Pyramid's `request.route_url()` system, or even just with tuples from the controller.

Comment: This is clearly the right answer - it helped me append '\' to the end of all but the last line when I was creating a multi-line statement in a script

Comment: Hi Francis, can I ask why is it not recommended? Is it due to security reasons? I was thinking of using similar method too. To query from server a list and publish the list on HTML as hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a list of `tuple`s for this. Pass them into the template such as:

```
{
   'my_list': [
        ('a', 'a_href',),
        ('b', 'b_href',),
    ]
}
```

And from your template, you should simply be able to do this:

```
{% for name, href in my_list %}
    <a href="{{href}}">{{name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the problem.  The problem is doing a Jinja2 `join` on the list of links.

Comment: @MFB: Sometimes the best answer is not the path that you're currently on. And to be clear, the ``join`` in Jinja2 isn't the *problem* you're trying to solve. Displaying a list of links *is*.

Comment: I'm trying to `join` a list of links.  That is the problem.  Not merely creating a list of links.  Thanks for your help anyway.